# How can I make an infinite fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering, how can I make a never ending fire in Minecraft? (I want to use it in SMP)

Answer (score 25):

You need to use a Netherrack block, as all other blocks burn up or won't catch on fire.

Nethererrack burns for ever.

Comment: There's always `/give <player> 87` on servers that have it enabled.

Comment: Ah, of course. Then netherrack then is the only available block.

Comment: If you are in the End, bedrock will also burn indefinitely

Answer (score 10):

Prior to the 1.3 patch, you could make an infinite fire by lighting a block of wood / log on fire so that only one side is burning, and it would stay infinitely burning. However, that was fixed in 1.3, so now the only way of having a block infinitely lit on fire is to get [Netherrack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether) somehow (be it buying it from an in-game shop, mining Coal Ore with a Golden Pickaxe if your server has the Golden Nether mod, or simply going to the Nether if your server supports it) and lighting it.

Comment: I thought forever burning logs was removed in a recent patch? [Indeed, it has been fixed in 1.3](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Fire#Eternal_Fire)

Comment: Ahh, I'll remove that then.

Answer (score 5):

There used to be a bug that allowed you to do infinite fire, however, it was removed.

Now the only way is to harvest Netherrack from the nether. Then you can use flint and steel to light it once you have placed the netherrack down.

In SMP you would need a nether world or use the /give command.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a netherrack block. Just mine it from the nether.

Alternatively, you could use `/give [user] 87` to get yourself a netherrack block.

This would be the only solution other than using a plugin.

Netherrack fires never burn out and if you want to read about them, check the  [Minecraft Wiki, Netherrack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Netherrack) article.

Comment: You may want to add the fact that the Nether is now also available in SMP in order to distinguish this answer from the rest.

Answer (score 3):

`/gamerule doFireTick false` will make all fires burn infinitely without spreading.

Answer (score 1):

You can harvest netherrack and use that, but unless you want a fireplace why get a never ending fire? Also, light the netherrack with a fire charge/flint and steel.

Comment: Because fire, that's why.

Comment: Give a man fire, he will be warm for a night.. give a man never ending fire .. Holy hell my wooden house is on fire.. way to much fire... because thats why.

Answer (score 1):

You need Netherrack, a block that makes fires burn unlimitedly.

## Netherrack

Netherrack can be found in the Nether, a dimensions that can be accessed by a portal built by 4 by 5 obsidian blocks. But keep the inner blocks empty. Then light the obsidian with flint and steel and the portal should be active. The Nether is full of Netherrack, so it's easy to collect. Once Netherrack is lit, the fire burns forever.

Answer (score 0):

yes infinite time fire is possible.

things you need:

- flint and steel (alternatively firecharge)
- netherrack that is found in nether.

netherrack looks like this (the block below the fire)  [image: block below the fire]

the nether rack is found in nether which looks like a hellish place. look the screenshot below [image]

Comment: Dude, this question was asked and answered 4 years ago.

Comment: oh! yeah. I just didn't check the date above...  :P